# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installer crashes

Tags: 12.04, installation, 32-bit

I am trying to install "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386" on my IBM M52 8213-W2B.  Currently I am using windows 8 consumer preview.

I am trying to install "ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386" by booting directly from usb flash drive.   The installer crashes just after creating new partition. The Apport report says that there is an error in the system log file which may be due to faulty media.

Comment: Did you verify the checksum of the iso that you downloaded? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: The checksums seem to be different. I will give it a try with the correct cheksum.Thank you harisibrahimkv.

Comment: @zubi did any of the answers work? If it did could you accept the answer (click the green check mark next to it), so that we know you solved your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the installer slide show first:

- Go to Software center -> All files
- search for "ubiquity-slideshow"
- click on the `Remove` button
- wait until the `Install` button appears (this may take a while).

Or from the command line: `sudo apt-get remove ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu`

The installer should work now.

Or, if you are installing Ubuntu Studio 12.04 LTS, for example : 
  `sudo apt-get remove ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntustudio`

Answer (score 2):

Unplug-in the Ethernet cable did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you! This helped me to fix the problem. I was installing Xubuntu 12.04 32bit into the clean PC, but the installation always crashed at the start with internal error: _ubiquity crashed with ValueError in raw_decode(): No JSON object could be decoded_. I have a kind of lame internet connection - you have to install a lot of software before you can connect properly to the internet. At installation start the xubuntu indicated that I'm offline but I guess I was just "half offline" and that confused the installer. And unplugging the cable helped.

Answer (score 1):

if the installer has already crash, and you got the black screen :

- ctrl-alt-F6
- killall Xorg
- startx

if you have "try ubuntu" before, just open the terminal :

```
sudo apt-get remove ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu
```

then you can start the installer again